# How to make "expand" static in list type

Tags: python

I'm a just beginner of python 3. 
I made three-times inner list like

```
[[[1, 0, 3], [1, 11, 1]], [[1, 0, 3], [1, 11, 1]]].
```

My question is how to expand the list statically.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
TestList0=[]
TestList_log=[]
for m in range(2):
    TestList = np.random.randint(0,4,3)
    TestList0.append([])
    TestList0[m].extend(TestList)

for time in range(3):
    TestList0[1][1] = TestList0[1][1]+5
    TestList_log.append([])
    TestList_log[time].extend(TestList0)    
    print(TestList_log)
```

and the output is

```
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 7, 0]]]
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 12, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 12, 0]]]
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 17, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 17, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 17, 0]]]
```

It seems "TestList0" is dynamically inserted.
What I want to obtain is

```
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 7, 0]]]
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 7, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 12, 0]]]
[[[2, 0, 1], [1, 7, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 12, 0]], [[2, 0, 1], [1, 17, 0]]]
```

How can I do it? It seems double inner list is static

```
for time in range(3):
    TestList0[1][1] = TestList0[1][1]+5
    TestList_log.append([])
    TestList_log[time].extend(TestList0[1])    
    print(TestList_log)
```

output is

```
[[1, 7, 3]]
[[1, 7, 3], [1, 12, 3]]
[[1, 7, 3], [1, 12, 3], [1, 17, 3]]
```

For me, it looks very strange to appear such difference between triple and double inner list.
I would appreciate any help and explanation. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by static in this context?

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm not confident about the use of "static" and "dynamic". What I meant is the update of value in TestList0 is taken over to TestList_log even after substitution. I expressed this phenomenon as "dynamic".

Comment: (If somebody wants to write this up as a full answer please do) When you call `newList.extend(oldList)` it copies each value from `oldList`to `newList`. If these values are immutable (e.g. an int or str), they will be "copied" in a way **similar** to pass-by-value in other languages. If they are immutable (e.g. a list, object etc.) they will be "copied" in a way **similar** to pass-by-reference. As such if you perform `newList.extend(aListOfLists)` each item of `aListOfLists` is "copied by reference" (not technically correct term) - and so if you mutate them later, the "copy" changes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to find solution by myself.
Let me share it.
This is matter of mutable or immutable, not statical or dynamical.

What I should have done is change

```
TestList_log[time].extend(TestList0)
```

into

```
import copy
TestList_log[time].extend(copy.deepcopy(TestList0))
```

Comment: This answer is definitely correct, please mark it as accepted - even though you wrote it yourself. There is nothing wrong with doing that.